# How to get current stage from Sharepoint 2013 with PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint

I want to make a website using following sharepoint api: http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/PHP_Read_and_write_to_SharePoint_Lists-PRF

I can easily retrieve my list, I can color or do whatever to that information in that list, but I want to get the current step of the workflow and make a red box under it and after is done a green box around it with arrows between them, to show they are connected. Is this something that can be done using PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use Camelot PHP Tools? https://camelotphptools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a workflow to a list it will create a column in the list with the same name as the workflow. It won't appear in List Settings, but will show in the list of fields to include in the list view. To get the stage(In Progress, Completed, etc.,) of a workflow is basically the same as reading any other column in a list.